# Copy and paste text from a div to another [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a thing that seems easy to me but I'm not very familiar with javascript language and I can't find any documentation to do what I want.

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
<div id="sourceA">Text</div>
<div id="sourceB">Another</div>

<div id="destination"></div>
```

Let's say I click on the "sourceA" div, the text contained in it should go in the "destination" div.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me? And maybe also suggest me somewhere I can go and learn something more about this code?

Comment: Do this https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery (note that jQuery is just JavaScript, and what you want to do is *really* simple, but SO isn't a how-to site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="sourceA" class="source">Text</div>
<div id="sourceB" class="source">Another</div>

<div id="destination"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.source').click(function(e) {
     $('#destination').text($(e.currentTarget).text())
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Read more about JavaScript and jQuery [events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/). What you need here is a `.click()` event on `sourceA` to handle your behaviour as follows:

```
$("#sourceA").click(function() {
    $("#destination").html($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example

```
var copyContentToDestinationClickHandler = function(event) {
    $('#destination').empty();
    $('#destination').append($(event.target).text());
}

$('#sourceA').click(copyContentToDestinationClickHandler);
$('#sourceB').click(copyContentToDestinationClickHandler);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7v5a6bsu/